# ¿Como convertir la fecha y hora en un texto? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date

por ejemplo:
28/03/2018 10:57:24
y al momento de registrar o actualizar que se aprecie: "Hace un instante", "Hace  una hora" en el xml

Comment: aquí [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) podrás leer sobre Time, un tipo que te permitirá hacer lo que quieres. A través de la fecha y hora actuales podrás determinar que cantidad de tiempo ha pasado entre la fecha y hora dada y el momento actual, y acto seguido, mediante texView.setText(<<TiempoTranscurrido>>) establecer el tiempo transcurrido en el intervalo.

Comment: Hola jeanD, agrega por favor lo que has investigado o el código que hayas tratado! Por cierto realiza el [tour] y revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quizas esto te ayude, primero se debe obtener la hora actual, luego formatear la hora que tienes en texto con SimpleDateFormat(), obtener los milisegundos de cada uno y restar estos.

```
Date actual= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    try {
        Date obtenida= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss").parse("28/03/2018 10:57:24");

        //tiempo en horas
        long tiempoTranscurrido = (actual.getTime()-obtenida.getTime())/1000/60/60;
        String texto="hace un momento";

        if(tiempoTranscurrido == 1)
            texto="hace una hora";
        else{
            if(tiempoTranscurrido < 24){
                texto="hace "+ tiempoTranscurrido+" horas";
            }
            else{
                //se puede filtrar como se quiera...dias, semanas...
            }
        }
        //mostrar texto en su textView o lo q desee
        // textView.setText(texto);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Ayúdanos a conservar la calidad de la información en el sitio, contestando preguntas que estén basadas en lo definido en el  [help], específicamente [ask]. Revisar [answer].